# Can I generate UUID in C++11?

Tags: c++11, uuid

Is there any build-in facility that allows to generate `UUID` in `C++11` without using any adidtional libraries?

Comment: @ildjarn why not turn your comment into an answer? A little more reputation for you, a clear response for others.

Comment: @Nicola : Fair enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>Reposted from comment:</sub>

Built-in facility, no. But if you use a third party library (as opposed to OS functionality), I strongly recommend [Boost.UUID](http://www.boost.org/libs/uuid/).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but another option is Poco's [UUIDGenerator](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.UUIDGenerator.html).

```
#include <Poco/UUID.h>
#include <Poco/UUIDGenerator.h>

auto uuid_str = Poco::UUIDGenerator().createRandom().toString();
```